# How to get senders address with bitcoinj (no duplicate)?

Tags: transactions, bitcoinj

I am using bitcoinj (java implementation). I have read many answers here but none of them answers my question. 
How to get senders address using bitcoinj?

I have transaction variable tx. I can get it's hash, I have used this as well: https://blockchain.info/tx/myTXhash and it showed me the transactions. The problem is not even that web is showing me the sender.

**BUT:** if I use that generated .wallet file and open it with multibit (bitcoin wallet) I can see there, under transactions, from who were the money sent. That means there is a way how to get senders address, but HOW?

**EDIT:** I was mistaken, multibit does not know from who the money came from, I was just confused because it showed me it was sent to the right address (but that was set up by me in args).

**But is there any possibility to get the message somehow from client to know if it is him who sent the money?**

Comment: Do you mean getting the Bitcoin address that sent the money or somehow getting a name?

Comment: Yes I mean Bitcoin address that sent the money. Or some other way how to check if the money came from that person. Consider it as a wallet which is receiving money constantly, but I need to check if it is coming from the ones who wants to access on a web.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference:
In bitcoinJ (java version) the input/output addresses of transactions are located in TransactionInput and TransactionOutput objects.

For example: for Transaction tx:

```
List<TransactionInput> inputs = tx.getInputs();
List<TransactionOutput> outputs = tx.getOutputs();

for(TransactionOutput out : outputs){
    System.out.println(out.getAddressFromP2PKHScript(params));
    System.out.println(out.getAddressFromP2SH(params));
}

for(TransactionInput in : inputs){
    System.out.println(in.getFromAddress());
}
```

Keep in mind that some transactions might not have an input address.
Here is the github description of getFromAddress() method:

> Convenience method that returns the from address of this input by parsing the scriptSig. The concept of a "from address" is not well defined in Bitcoin and you should not assume that senders of a transaction can actually receive coins on the same address they used to sign (e.g. this is not true for shared wallets).

Answer (score 1):

You can see the addresses that sent and received money when looking at a transaction on most services. For example:

https://blockchain.info/tx/c6cb02e70442275ffb7b35cc8a9416323ff7e01b5378abc20ae7f5b6e7617884

The big green arrow shows the transfer from one address (1B898F2tcWHX1LZWWfD21FRzqWrtXLocXN) to the 2 others. Programmatically you could use an API that returns JSON with equivalent information:

https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/txs/c6cb02e70442275ffb7b35cc8a9416323ff7e01b5378abc20ae7f5b6e7617884

However it isn't straightforward to extract this information when looking at a raw transaction as the addresses are embedded in the script.